# Modifying a table in django admin panel by editing another table

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin

I want to be able to delete some elements in a model after editing the name of a field and answering a question.
This are my models:

```
class Cursuri(models.Model):
    id_curs = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    titlu_curs = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    an = models.IntegerField()
    semestru = models.IntegerField()
    credite = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Cursuri"


class Note(models.Model):
    nr_matricol = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    id_curs = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    valoare = models.IntegerField()
    data_notare = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Note"
```

When i edit the name of the field "titlu_curs" i want to delete the elements from "Note" that have the same "id_curs" as the one modified in "Cursuri"

I tried doing this:

```
class CursuriAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ("an","semestru","credite", )
    list_display=("id_curs","titlu_curs","an","semestru","credite",)
    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            new_name = request.POST.get('titlu_curs')

            old_name = Cursuri.objects.get(id=object_id).titlu_curs
            id_curs = Cursuri.objects.get(id=object_id).id_curs

            Cursuri.objects.get(id=object_id).titlu_curs=new_name
            


            if new_name != old_name:

                return render(request,'vizualizare/confirmare_subiect.html',context={
                    'new_name': new_name,
                    'old_name': old_name,
                    "id_curs":id_curs,
                    }
                )
        return super().change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
```

and this is the template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <form action="admin/vizualizare/cursuri/<int:pk>/change" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h2>Is the new subject "{{ nume_nou }}" related to the previous subject "{{ nume_vechi }}"?</h2>
        <input type="submit" value="Yes, it is related" name="Yes"/>
        <input type="submit" value="No, it is not related" name="No"/>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

I want to delete the values in "Note" if the answer is no but after answering the question I get redirected to the table "Cursuri" and not even the name I edit changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `save()` the object after modifying it.

```
obj = Cursuri.objects.get(id=object_id)
obj.titlu_curs=new_name
obj.save()
```

To implement the deletion of the notes, you'll have to create a new view that handles the submitted forms.